# Xamarin Forms 4.11.0 error: No property, bindable property or event found for UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I met strange error for UWP from following xaml:`

```
<sfPager:SfDataPager.HeightRequest>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"  
                  UWP="40"
                  Android="50"
                  iOS="50"/>                 
 </sfPager:SfDataPager.HeightRequest>
```

When compiling, I got the following error:

```
No property, bindable property, or event found for 'UWP', or mismatching type between value and property.
```

what am I doing wrong here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<sfPager.SfDataPager HeightRequest="{OnPlatform UWP=40, iOS=50, Android=50}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Platform Differences with OnPlatform:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="40"></On>
    <On Platform="Android" Value="50"></On>
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="50"></On>
</OnPlatform>
```

re: [Platform Differences with OnPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax)

Comment: @maryam Forms version 4.11.0? The latest preview version of 4.x is `4.0.0.135214-pre5`